# TypeScript interface to catch objects with any amount of values

Tags: typescript, types, structural-typing

I have an object like this:

```
{
    "0001": "a",
    "0002": "b",
    "0003": "c",
    ...
}
```

Can I write a TypeScript interface, which describes this type?

Comment: Other than `{ [key: string]: string }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NitzanTomer's comment is totally valid: interface Map `{ [key: string]: string }`.

You can also define it as a literal, or as just strings:

```
interface LiteralInterface { 
    "0001": "a",
    "0002": "b",
    "0003": "c",
     ...
}

interface StringInterface { 
    "0001": string,
    "0002": string,
    "0003": string,
     ...
}
```

but here you do have to specify each and every property...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this:

```
interface StringInterface {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```